# Bash script: How to extract some values from a variable?

Tags: bash

I want to create an Bash alias to show system information (similar to screenfetch or neofetch, but lighter).
Currently the code is:

```
function info {
echo
kernel=$(uname -s -r)
echo $kernel"."
echo
packages=$(pacman -Qq | wc -l)
echo $packages "packages."
echo
df /dev/mmcblk1p2 -h
echo
sensors coretemp-isa-0000 -A
}
```

The result is:

```
Linux 5.2.0-arch2-1-ARCH.

927 packages.

Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mmcblk1p2   57G   26G   29G  48% /

coretemp-isa-0000
Package id 0:  +46.0°C  (high = +105.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 0:        +46.0°C  (high = +105.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 1:        +46.0°C  (high = +105.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 2:        +45.0°C  (high = +105.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 3:        +45.0°C  (high = +105.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
```

I want to load part of the output of the df and sensors commands into another variable.

For df: I want to extract the value of Size, Used, Avail and Use% to show: The disk has $disk_size. A $disk_percent ($used) has been used. $disk_avail are free.

For sensors:  I want to extract the value of 'Package id 0' to show: The CPU has $cpu_temperature.

Comment: `awk` might be a very good solution to this

Comment: That's a function, not an alias.

Comment: Why not just use the `df` output as it is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could grab the information as part of the function and store it in a variable as opposed to trying to get the information from the function output as displayed in `diskInfo` and `cpuTempInfo` below:

```
function info {
echo
kernel=$(uname -s -r)
echo $kernel"."
echo
packages=$(pacman -Qq | wc -l)
echo $packages "packages."
echo
df /dev/mmcblk1p2 -h
diskInfo=$(df /dev/mmcblk1p2 -h | awk 'FNR > 1 { print "Disk Size:" $2 " with " $3 " used. " $4 " available " $5 " of disk used " }')
echo $diskInfo
echo
sensors coretemp-isa-0000 -A
cpuTempInfo=$(sensors coretemp-isa-0000 -A | awk 'FNR == 2 { print $4 }'
echo $cpuTempInfo
}
```

`echo $diskInfo`

```
Disk Size:57G with 26G used. 29G available 48% of disk used
```

`echo $cpuTempInfo`

```
 +46.0°C
```